# Why Can't I delete or Remove iPhone / iPad Duplicate Enterprise App Icon Copy?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, duplicates, enterprise

I created an enterprise app in Xcode 4.6.3 and posted it on a website. The app succesfully downloads to iPhone5 and iPad3 (both running iOS 7). The app runs just fine. However, it created a duplicate "ghosted" app icon on both devices that cannot be removed [See Screen Capture](http://www.mmprod.com/PICS/enterprise.jpg).

I tried removing it by long-pressing the app icon and touching the "X" on the device. I also tried removing it in iTunes. No luck. I updated to Xcode 5.0.1, developed for iOS 7, recompiled and repeated the process. No luck. The duplicate icon remains!

This is not an issue on devices not running iOS 7.

Answer (score 0):

A similar thing happened to me while trying to delete an app that was being built at the same time with XCode.

**Try restarting the phone by pressing and holding the button on the top and the circle button on the bottom.**

When the OS repopulates the dashboard on the next launch, it should detect the discrepancy and either not display the bad icon or make it available for removal.

Answer (score -1):

If your Apps don't includ iOS, you are surely able to delete Apps from iPhone, do all of your 3rd party apps no longer show the delete "x" when wiggling? If so, try the following steps as needed:

1. Restart phone
2. Reset phone (no data loss): press both home and power buttons for at least 10 seconds, releasing when the Apple logo appears
3. Settings > General > Reset > Reset All Settings
4. Restore iOS using iTunes, also restoring a backup
5. Restore iOS as new, without using a backup